# Хочу React intellisense в уже имеющемся проекте asp.net visual studio

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio, asp.net

У меня есть проект asp net, и мне понадобился react. С основной частью я справился и react работает. Но так как я в прошлом не использовал react, то хочу подключить intellisense, чтобы упростить себе задачу по обучению. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А, виноват, я ничего не импортировал, по этому оно не работало.